# How do I set environment variables through a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: bash, shortcut-keys, environment-variables

I have a script that increments an environment variable, but it only works if I run it by perpending it with "source" or with a ".". Unfortunately, this means that if I attempt to bind it to a key, I can't seem to use "source" modifier, thus the environment variables don't actually change.

(Assuming an integer TEST already exists within shell environment):

```
#!/bin/bash

let "TEST=$TEST+1"
echo $TEST
export TEST=$TEST
```

Ideally this script would increment the test variable, but (if I understand this right) it only does so in the "sub-shell" environment that this scripts spawns when it is run. Is it possible modify an environment variable in this way without using "source"? If not, how else could I accomplish my goal? I'd appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Which way would you bind it to a key? Inside `bash`/`readline`? And how would you use it?

Comment: The way I've been binding keys thus far is through the Keyboard part of the settings window (under the "Application Shortcuts" tab of the Keyboard window). A key I could use while operating in a GUI. I'm trying to write a toggle for disabling my track pad. But it seems I can't query whether it's disabled or not, only disable and enable it so I decided to keep track of this via a global variable. But even if there's an alternate solution to that, I would still like to know if there's a way to accomplish this task, or a workaround.

Comment: For the track pad, it should be possible to check the disabled state with something like `xinput list-props 13 | grep 'Device Enabled.*1'` for device 13 - see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad

Comment: Gah! I was looking for that for literally an hour! I'm used to scouring docs but the man pages just felt ridiculous, I totally missed that this info was even present. I was thinking it seemed weird that it wasn't... Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is probably to store the variable in a file.

Write to a file:

`echo "13" > /path/to/my-variable.txt`

Read the first line in a file into the variable `line`:

`read -r line < /path/to/my-variable.txt`

Comment: Great idea! I finished the script using this. If possible, I'd like to do this without an extraneous file because that will grow bulky and difficult to maneuver with time, but for the foreseeable future this will work just fine, thanks!

Comment: @user2840488 I think you will need the file - where else do you want to save the variable value? There are other ways, but they are more complicated.

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction? I totally understand if it's over my head, I'm a java guy so most of this syntax is just stopping me dead in my tracks, but I'd like something in the back of my mind I could take another crack at in a few months when I'm not so green. Thanks for the help again!

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the answer provided about using a .txt file, you could probably do something with a simple key-value store like redis or memcached (or a db, but that's really overkill).

```
$ sudo apt-get install redis-server redis-tools

$ redis-cli SET testing 5
OK

$ redis-cli GET testing 
"5"
```